# Does home directory encryption depend on gnome keyring?

Tags: encryption, gnome-keyring

My **gnome-keyring** has somehow gotten messed up. It prompts for a password (that I know I never provided - yes I chose 'unsafe storage'). None of the possible passwords that I use (including empty) are working.

So basically I want to delete the default key so I can start over.  I just want to confirm that this isn't somehow tied to my home directory encryption.  I want to be sure that if I delete the default key from it, I will still be able to log in normally and decrypt my home directory.  It seems likely that they're unrelated as the keyring is within the home directory and is thus itself encrypted, but I just thought I'd ask.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: This thread seems to support my theory that the Gnome keyring is unrelated to home-dir encryption: http://ubuntu.5.n6.nabble.com/encrypted-home-dir-tale-of-woe-td1347236.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu uses `eCryptfs` to encrypt home.

I don't think gnome-keyring is related. You may want to look into the following file:

```
/root/.ecryptfsrc
```

For more information:

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/ecryptfs.html

Comment: I went ahead and deleted the default key and logged out then back in again.  All is well.  I had figured it would be ok, but while I was in the middle of some heavy production I didn't want to risk disabling my system.